# SQL Merge Quantity of Variation (mother item)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I'm no SQL professional by all means. So please excuse some false assumptions weird code etc.
I'm currently trying to merge the quantity of all items for the ebay marketplace. I already managed to update nearly all items. But I do hassle a bit with some specific items which are also located in our database. Each variation item has a (mother item) which is displayed in our ERP system.
These mother items do have an Variation-ID (0). Other variations do have variation.ids for specific colors (f.e. black = 1 , green = 2, and so on).
Since our ERP system does set the lowest quantity (for the mother item) of a variation item in some masks to perform a trigger (revise of all items), to prevent from overselling, I need to update the quantity of the mother item with the lowest quantity related to the variation.

The following statements

> EI.tecdocinfo = lbs.shop
> WHEN matched AND LBS.shop = '0'

where just for me to help identifying each item. They do work flawlessly.

The source table does have the following important rows:
Item number , variation id, quantity

```
using(SELECT *
      FROM   lbsysstock) AS LBS
ON EI.artikelnummer = lbs.artikelnummer
   AND EI.tecdocinfo = lbs.shop
WHEN matched AND LBS.shop = '0' THEN
  UPDATE SET EI.quantity = (SELECT Min(verfuegbar) - '1'
                            FROM   lbsysstock
                            WHERE  EI.artikelnummer = LBS.artikelnummer);
```

My current problem is the last part with updating the items using a sub select query.

For example item number 100001 does have 3 variants (black, green, blue)

| Item number | Item ID | Quantity | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 0 | 0 | mother item |
| 100001 | 1 | 66 | black |
| 100001 | 2 | 55 | green |
| 100001 | 3 | 77 | blue |

In this case I would need the quantity of the green item substracted minus 1.

Answer (score -1):

The code:

```
DECLARE
  @Quantity
  TABLE
  (
    item_number     int,
    shop_id         smallint,
    quantity        tinyint,
    colour          varchar(10)
  )
;

DECLARE
  @Destination
  TABLE
  (
    item_number     int,
    shop_id         tinyint,
    min_quantity    tinyint
  )
;

INSERT INTO 
  @Quantity
(
  item_number, shop_id, quantity, colour
)
VALUES
  ( 100001, 0, 0, 'mother' ),
  ( 100001, 1, 66, 'black' ),
  ( 100001, 2, 55, 'green' ),
  ( 100001, 3, 77, 'blue' )
;

INSERT INTO 
  @Destination
(
  item_number, shop_id, min_quantity
)
VALUES
  ( 100001, 0, 20 ),
  ( 100001, 2, 30 ),
  ( 100002, 0, 30 )
;

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @Quantity
;
SELECT
  *
FROM
  @Destination
;

WITH
  cte_min_quantity
(
  item_number,
  min_quantity
)
AS
(
  SELECT
    item_number,
    Min( quantity ) -1
  FROM
    @Quantity
  WHERE
      shop_id <> 0
  GROUP BY
    item_number
)
/* -- debug
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cte_min_quantity
*/
MERGE INTO @Destination AS Dest
  USING cte_min_quantity AS Src
    ON  Src.item_number = Dest.item_number
  WHEN MATCHED AND Dest.shop_id = 0
    THEN
    UPDATE SET
      Dest.min_quantity = Src.min_quantity
;

SELECT
  *
FROM
   @Destination
;
```

Algorithm:

- Pre-aggregate by item_number to minimum quantity from the source
- Use a CTE to prepare the data
- Join Destination to CTE and update only if the shop indicates the mother item

A few remarks:

- MERGE is more powerful and transaction friendly than INSERT / UPDATE with the cost it is harder to debug
- CTEs prefer to work in memory and will spill into tempdb on disk if too big

Comment: "MERGE is more powerful and transaction friendly than INSERT / UPDATE with the cost it is harder to debug" - totally incorrect regarding the transaction. Without hints, MERGE is not atomic.

Comment: "CTEs prefer to work in memory" - do you have concrete evidence for that? I suggest reading: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

Comment: @MitchWheat The link is good and hence the statement "prefer to work in memory" - like any data collection if it is not in memory no query engine will work with the data. Therefore the massive amount of memory for In Memory DMBS engines like HANA. If data becomes too big even a table variable will spill to disk. Main evidence comes from a lot of execution plan investigations - Spools in particular are indicative. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/simplepod/Complete_Showplan_Operators_Fabiano_Amorim%20%28without%20video%29.pdf

Comment: I know what spools are, thanks. This statement " like any data collection if it is not in memory no query engine will work with the data " is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @KnutBoehnert sadly I don't know anything about CTE. Isn't there a simplified way of getting the needed data? I don't want to insert any data in the existing tables. I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio for everything. Maybe you or anyone else could be so kind and lead me step by step to the solution.